# Calculate total once checkbox is checked using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to create a javascript code for my website to do the calculations once a checkbox is checked. Each time i select a checkbox it should calculate the total price of the items.

This is my html code:

```
<form id="orderForm" action="#" method="get">
    <section id="selectBook">
        <h2>Select books</h2>
        <?php
        include_once('database_conn.php');
        $sqlBooks = 'SELECT bookISBN, bookTitle, bookYear, catDesc,  bookPrice FROM nbc_book b inner join nbc_category c on b.catID = c.catID WHERE 1 order by bookTitle';
        $rsBooks = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlBooks);
        while ($book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsBooks)) {
            echo "\t<div class='item'>
                    <span class='bookTitle'>{$book['bookTitle']}</span>
                    <span class='bookYear'>{$book['bookYear']}</span>
                    <span class='catDesc'>{$book['catDesc']}</span>
                    <span class='bookPrice'>{$book['bookPrice']}</span>
                    <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='book[]' value='{$book['bookISBN']}' title='{$book['bookPrice']}' /></span>
                </div>\n";
        }
        ?>
    </section>

    <section id="collection">
        <h2>Collection method</h2>
        <p>Please select whether you want your chosen book(s) to be delivered to your home address (a charge applies for this) or whether you want to collect them yourself.</p>
        <p>
        Home address - &pound;3.99 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" title="3.99" checked = "checked" />&nbsp; | &nbsp;
        Collect from warehouse - no charge <input type="radio"  name="deliveryType" value="trade" title="0" />
        </p>
    </section>

    <section id="checkCost">
        <h2>Total cost</h2>
        Total <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
    </section>
```

The code has been separated into  tag.

This is my current javascript code which i have written:

```
var item = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    var chkbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i = 0; i < chkbox.length; i++){
        chkbox[i].onchange = function(){
            //Recalculate total
            getTotal();
        }
    }

    function getTotal(){
        var total = 0.0;

        for(var i = 1; i <= chkbox.length; i++){
            //If the checkbox is checked, add it to the total
            if(chkbox[i-1].checked){
                total = total + parseFloat(chkbox[i].value);
            }
        }

        return total;

        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
    }
```

I really need some experts to help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: what is the actual problem? desired vs actual behavior?

Comment: @geert3 I cant get the total price of the books once i checked on my checkbox.

Comment: I see at one place you use `i-1` as index in the array, the next line you use `i`.

Comment: @geert3 actually it should parse the value instead of title, i will edit back again

Comment: No actually I think `title` is OK as your PHP code says `title='{$book['bookPrice']}'`. I think the index is the issue. Suggest you single-step through the javascript using "developer tools", (F12 in most browsers, or the FireBug plugin for firefox)

Comment: @geert3 I am sorry but the console does not show any errors

Comment: You don't need expertise help here. You do need to make clear what's the problem. And also to show us the rendered `HTML`, without the irrelevant `PHP` bits.

Comment: @MelanciaUK the problem is I dont know how to do the javascript code to get the price of the book each time a checkbox is checked. I am totally new to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In `getTotal()` you are returning before setting the value here:

   `return total;`
   `document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;`
2. Set the input with the value rather than `innerHTHML`.

   `document.getElementById("total").setAttribute("value", total);`
3. I had to change the checked to be `parseFloat(chkbox[i-1].title)` to match the if statement

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rm6qzp2/5/)**

The above example uses to products, the first priced at 1 and the second at 2.